# Disabling "symlink follow" feature on Ext3/4 mount points

Tags: linux, mount, ext3, symbolic-link

How can I disable the symlink feature of ext3 file system mount point ?
My server is being attacked by some sort of symbolic link hacking methods for reading other user's home directory.
There is such an option "nosymfollow" on BSD series, but I didn't find the equivalent for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such option for ext3 or ext4, to the best of my knowledge. Maybe if you described the actual nature of your problem someone could propose a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is an option for this.  Perhaps if this is through something like Apache a Directive might solve the problem.

You could of course blow away all the symlinks under a specific directory:

```
find . -type l -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, ext3 doesn't have support for this, ufs on bsd does.  I'm not sure what context this is happening in, but I'm going to assume that some portion of users home directories is being served up by apache, which if you have the "FollowSymLinks" option enabled can cause issues.  You'd want to disable this if this is the case, but you'd really have to provide more info as to what is actually happening for a more detailed or better solution.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#options